# From a given triangle, to cut 2 mutually congruent convex pieces that together 'use' maximum area of the triangle

Tags: mg.metric-geometry, discrete-geometry

Two planar regions are congruent if one can be made to perfectly coincide with the other by translation, rotation or reﬂection (ﬂipping over).

**The Problem:** Given a triangular region T, how will we cut from it, 2 mutually congruent convex pieces that together use the highest fraction of the area of T? Let us call such a partition, the best congruent 2-partition of T.

And which is the specific shape of triangle T such that the largest fraction of its area gets left over (’wasted’) under its best congruent 2-partition?

**Note:** One can generalize from T and ask for a general convex region C that 'wastes' the largest fraction its area when given its best congruent 2-partition.

An attempt on this question was posted in

- R Nandakumar, *Cutting Mutually Congruent Pieces from Convex Regions*, arXiv:[1012.3106](https://arxiv.org/abs/1012.3106).

Please note that the document discusses only partitions into convex pieces. I am not aware of any conclusive results on this question.

**A variant** (this bit is being added following this later post: [On finding optimal convex planar shapes to cover a given convex planar shape](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/412052/on-finding-optimal-convex-planar-shapes-to-cover-a-given-convex-planar-shape) ): One can also try to find 2 - or in general n - mutually congruent convex regions of *maximum perimeter* that can be drawn inside a given triangle T or general convex region C and compare this optimal region with the maximally area utilizing one drawn inside T.

Comment: This formulation is unclear. If you divide a region into pieces, how does that not cover all of the region? Are you looking for the largest duomino that fits in a triangle?  I am inventing the term duonimo to describe the disjoint union of two convex regions which are congruent.  Gerhard "Duonimo Should Be A Word" Paseman, 2020.02.12.

Comment: Thank you. I meant how to cut FROM T  two convex pieces that together 'use' the highest fraction of the area of T. Edited question to reflect this better.

Comment: I was wondering if this problem is equivalent to finding the largest isosceles triangles fitting inside the given one, but is seems that the linked paper offers clever counterexamples to that.

Comment: Yes. experiments indicate one can 'use' more of the given triangle if the two congruent pieces are allowed to have more than 3 sides, at least for some input triangles. But in that document, I couldn't prove much conclusively.