# Covering triangles with mutually congruent planar regions - optimally

Tags: mg.metric-geometry, discrete-geometry, computational-geometry, packing-and-covering

We continue from this old post: [From a given triangle, to cut 2 mutually congruent convex pieces that together 'use' maximum area of the triangle](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/352563/) and go from partitioning to covering.

- Given an arbitrary unit area triangle, how can we **cover** it fully with 2 mutually congruent connected planar regions (call this pair the 'covering pieces') of least area? Does allowing the covering piece to be non-convex improve the covering (ie reduce the area of a covering piece) at least in some cases?
- Since not all triangles can be cut neatly into two mutually congruent regions, the covering will in general need regions with area more than half of the triangle. So, for which shape of unit area triangle will the covering region have largest area? In other words, which unit area triangle is the 'worst' for covering with 2 mutually congruent planar regions?

**Note:** If we consider covering general convex planar regions (not triangles) with 2 mutually congruent covering pieces, allowing the covering region to be non-convex can reduce the area of the covering pieces at least in some cases - see the answer to [A claim on partitioning a convex planar region into congruent pieces](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/370302/a-claim-on-partitioning-a-convex-planar-region-into-congruent-pieces). Not sure if using non-convex covering pieces can help in covering triangles optimally though.

**Further remarks:**

- Guess: covering would need to consider more cases than partitioning because the covering regions could either project out from the triangle being covered or overlap in its interior (in partitioning, there are no overlaps). So it is not clear to what extent solving the question (in link at the top) of *cutting* 2 mutually congruent pieces from a triangle of maximum possible area could help in the present problem.
- Going from 2 congruent covering pieces to to n or even 3 could make the present question extremely hard.